# PhpStorm keyboard shortcut for code inspection recommended resolution?

Tags: phpstorm

If you run a code inspection, you might get something like this in the results panel:

```
Problem synopsis:
Traditional syntax array literal detected (at line 193)

Problem resolution:
Convert Array Syntax To Short
```

i.e. it's telling you to change array() to []

The 'resolution' is clickable and it'll fix it for you.  But is a keyboard shortcut, or a way of shading identical problems (often you get a bunch of them) and having them fixed for you all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use f2/Shift+f2 to jump to next/previous error, then hit Alt+Enter, Enter to apply suggested fixes.
Note that there is a Code | Code Cleanup... command that runs inspections against your code and applies quickfixes. But it only includes a small subset of available inspections that are considered 'safe', so that applying hotfixes automatically doesn't break anything

Answer (score 1):

Use standard shortcut: same as for invoking intentions menu (Quick Fix menu) manually in Editor: <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> (for Windows/Linux, not sure what that would be on Mac)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can take a look at this tool: https://github.com/fabpot/PHP-CS-Fixer